# What is wrong with my export path?

Tags: path, bash

I have downloaded Eclipse from http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html
I have unpacked and call it from eclipse folder.BBUt when I try to export the path by adding this line

```
export PATH="/home/milenko/eclipse/eclipse:$PATH"
```

to my bashrc

```
./eclipse
bash: ./eclipse: Is a directory
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply that BASH gives should give you the answer: ./eclipse is a directory. Try

```
ls -l
```

It will give you that eclipse is a directory, not an executable file.

Anyway, if you do

```
./eclipse
```

the bash will try to execute eclipse in the current directory and the PATH is therefore irrelevant.

I have not installed eclipse, so I might be wrong, but

```
export PATH="/home/milenko/eclipse/eclipse:$PATH"
```

seems wrong to me; I would have expected the executable eclipse to be in the directory /home/milenko/eclipse. The PATH variable should contain directories where executables are.

Try the following:

```
eclipse/eclipse
```

If that works, you should

```
export PATH="/home/milenko/eclipse:$PATH"
```

and start eclipse with

```
eclipse
```

(without the ./)